# Winapi button pressed down

Tags: c, windows, winapi, button

How to detect if button is pressed down (in C winapi)? By button I mean a part of interface, NOT a keyboard button or mouse button. I'm creating buttons as a default push button and they are sending only WM_COMMAND messages after clicking, but I need also to get a message when button is in down state. How to achieve it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Which is unlikely to do anything since a button generates the notification when it was released.  High odds that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I need to set a certain bit in certain external register to 1 when button is down and then to 0 when button is released, that's why I need two notfications from button - one when pressing it down and second after relasing.

Comment: @WernerHenze have you ever heard the *MouseDown* event in VB or C#? There is there for a reason. *Why do you need to know that?* .If you dont know don't comment.

Comment: For anyone having this problem the answer is that the button must have the **BS_OWNERDRAW** style. In *WM_DRAWITEM* message you check the state of the button.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I am not sure why you are talking to me. I don't see any previous comment or Action from me on this post!?

Answer (score 0):

When receiving the WM_COMMAND, simply check for BN_PUSHED or BN_UNPUSHED, instead of BN_CLICKED.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The button probably needs to be created with the BS_PUSHBUTTON style set.

Comment: *BS_PUSHBUTTON* style doesnt do anything cause it is zero